# Getting breakpoint/crash when trying to convert array

Tags: ios, arrays, converters, breakpoints

Getting a breakpoint/crash on the line

`if ([[status objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:(@"VM running")])`

Not sure why, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *status = [dictValue valueForKeyPath:@"VM_LIST.SERVER_STATUS_MSG"];
                     NSLog(@"%@", status);
                     int i = 0;
                     NSLog(@"%@", [status objectAtIndex:i]);
                     while (i <= [status count])
                     {
                         if ([[status objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:(@"VM running")])
                             {
                                 [statuses addObject:@"check.png"];
                             }
                         else
                             [statuses addObject:@"x.png"];
                         i++;
                     }
```

The `NSLog` for status is:

```
(
    "VM running",
    "VM running",
    "VM running"
)
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post that and an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: Move `NSLog(@"%@", [status objectAtIndex:i]);` just inside the loop and add the results to the question.

Comment: *WHAT* "breakpoint/crash"???  What is the message???

Comment: Although one can guess that it's something about an index out of bounds: `while (i <= [status count])` -- Do you see anything wrong with that??

Comment: (If you had actually **looked** at the exception message you'd have known right away what the problem was.)

Comment: 2014-10-28 10:23:42.852 FDCC Cloud Manager[1359:37646] VM running
2014-10-28 10:23:42.852 FDCC Cloud Manager[1359:37646] VM running
2014-10-28 10:23:42.852 FDCC Cloud Manager[1359:37646] VM running
(lldb)

Comment: I changed it and removed the equal sign, no more crashing

Comment: Great to hear that, thanks for reading my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some weird things I notice:

```
if ([[status objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:(@"VM running")])
```

shouldn't that be without the ()'s:

```
if ([[status objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"VM running"])
```

This seems to take one too much (out of bounds):

```
while (i <= [status count])
```

I think it should be:

```
while (i < [status count])
```

Or even better, just the safest way:

```
for (NSString *statusString in status) {
    if ([statusString isEqualToString:@"VM running"]) {
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", statuses); is giving null. Why is that? Am I not doing addobject properly?

Comment: I used the for loop and the addobject commands from my old code

Comment: Oops forgot statuses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; , nevermind. Thanks a lot though!